# Would using READ_UNCOMMITED/DIRTY isolation reduce most RDMS overhead?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, cap-theorem

I'm trying to figure out the overheads of RDMS as opposed to BASE databases to keep data consistent, atomic, and transactional. I'm just curious, would using ***READ_UNCOMMITED/DIRTY*** isolation reduce most of RDMS overhead? If not, why not?

Comment: hava a read this http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tamarick_hill/archive/2013/05/06/pros-cons-of-using-read-uncommitted-and-nolock.aspx

Comment: @JerryChin Nice article. I'm more interested in, though, if using `READ_UNCOMMITED/DIRTY` would eliminate enough overhead to compete against `BASE` databases - e.g. Mongo. (Since the argument against RDMS is keeping data consistent and atomic.)

Comment: They are two different things, it is hard to compare with each other.